# Related Videos with part contentDetails and Statistics - Youtube API V3

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm having a problem with retrieving related videos as thumbnails towards a specific video. In my code, I have the `search->list` set up correctly and returns the different titles and thumbnail URLs for the related videos. However, since `search->list` doesn't have parameter `contentDetails` or `statistics`, I found another question related to my exact same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137227/gdata-api-v3-youtube-can-not-retrieve-contentdetails) and used a secondary call for getting `videos->list` since it supports those parameters to be able to retrieve the duration and view count. But the problem is that both values (`vidDuration` & `viewCount`) are not being passed anything and marked as undefined as the item is passed through it and halted. How can I make the item's `duration` and `viewCount` values based on `search->list`'s item?

**script.js:**

```
function relatedVids(videoId)
{
    debugger;
    $.get( // get related videos related to videoId - relatedToVideoId
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search",
        {
            part: 'snippet',
            maxResults: vidResults,
            relatedToVideoId: videoId, // $.cookie("id"); from single-video.html
            type: 'video',
            key: 'XXXXXXXXX'
        },

        function(data)
        {
            $.each(data.items,
                function(i, item)
                {
                    console.log(item);
                    var vidTitle = item.snippet.title; // video title
                    //var videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId; // video id
                    //var vidDuration = item.contentDetails.duration;
                    //var viewCount = item.statistics.viewCount;
                    var vidThumbUrl = item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url; // video thumbnail url
                    var extractVideoId = null; // var to extract video id string from vidThumbUrl

                    // check if vidThumbUrl is not null, empty string, or undefined
                    if(vidThumbUrl)
                    {
                        //console.log("vidThumbUrl: ", vidThumbUrl);
                        var split = vidThumbUrl.split("/"); // split string when '/' seen
                        extractVideoId = split[4]; // retrieve the fourth index on the fourth '/'
                        //console.log("extractVideoId: ", extractVideoId); // YE7VzlLtp-4
                        //console.log("split array: ", split);
                    }
                    else console.error("vidThumbUrl is either undefined or null or empty string."); 
                    // if video title is longer than 25 characters, insert the three-dotted ellipse
                    if(vidTitle.length > 25)
                    {
                        var strNewVidTitle = vidTitle.substr(0, 25) + "...";
                        vidTitle = strNewVidTitle;
                    }

                    // search->list only takes snippet, so to get duration and view count; have to call this function that has the recognized param structure
                    $.get(
                        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos",
                        {
                            part: 'contentDetails, statistics',
                            id: extractVideoId, //item.snippet.resourceId.videoId,
                            key: 'XXXXXXXXX',
                        },
                        // return search->list item's duration and view count
                        function(item)
                        {
                            vidDuration = item.contentDetails.duration; // pass item's duration
                            return vidDuration;
                        },
                        function(item)
                        {
                            viewCount = item.statistics.viewCount; // pass item's view count
                            return viewCount;
                        }
                    );


                    try
                    {
                        var vidThumbnail = '<div class="video-thumbnail"><a class="thumb-link" href="single-video.html"><div class="video-overlay"><img src="imgs/video-play-button.png"/></div><img src="' + vidThumbUrl + '" alt="No Image Available." style="width:204px;height:128px"/></a><p><a class="thumb-link" href="single-video.html">' + vidTitle + '</a><br/>' + convert_time(vidDuration) + ' / Views: ' + viewCount + '</p></div>';

                        // print results
                        $('.thumb-related').append(vidThumbnail);
                    }
                    catch(err)
                    {
                        console.error(err.message); // log error but continue operation    
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    );
}
```

**single-video.html script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var videoId;
    $(function() 
    {
        if($.cookie("title") != null && $.cookie("id") != null)
        {
            var data = '<div class="video"><iframe height="' + vidHeight + '" width="' + vidWidth + '" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/' + $.cookie("id") + '\"></iframe></div><div class="title">' + $.cookie("title") + '</div><div class="desc">' + $.cookie("desc") + '</div><div class="duration">Length: ' + $.cookie("dur") + '</div><div class="stats">View Count: ' + $.cookie("views") + '</div>';

            $("#video-display").html(data);
            $("#tab1").html($.cookie("desc"));

            videoId = $.cookie("id");
            //vidDuration = $.cookie("dur"); works but prints out the same value for each
            //viewCount = $.cookie("views"); works but prints out the same value for each
            debugger;
            relatedVids(videoId); // called here


            console.log("from single-vid.html globalPlaylistId: ", $.cookie("playlistId"));


            // remove cookies after transferring it to this page for display
            $.removeCookie("title");
            $.removeCookie("id");
            $.removeCookie("desc");
            $.removeCookie("views");
            $.removeCookie("dur");
            $.removeCookie("tags");
            $.removeCookie("playlistId");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're referring the `item` in the search results. 
When you issued a get request to videos, you will get a response of video contentDetails and statistics. Apparently, you didn't capture the returned response.

```
   $.get(
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos",
                    {
                        part: 'contentDetails, statistics',
                        id: videoId, //item.snippet.resourceId.videoId,
                        key: 'XXXXXXXXX',
                    },

                    function(videoItem) 
                    {
                        vidDuration = videoItem.contentDetails.duration; // pass item's duration
                        viewCount = videoItem.statistics.viewCount; // pass item's view count
                    }
                );
```

NOTE: You can pass a string of video IDs delimited by a comma to fetch multiple video contentDetails/statistics in one request.

Comment: Do you mind showing me an example in code-form please? Thank you!

Comment: I edited my code and refined a few things such as only having one parameter for the function `relatedVids(videoId)` and `return` keyword with vidDuration and viewCount based on what you said, but for some reason, the `$.get()` object from videoId for getting `vidDuration` and `viewCount` is there, but both values still having nothing and remains null.

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight You didn't get my point. Initially, you callback function for the `videos` get request didn't have any parameters, which means you silently ignores the returned response. So I revised your code to pass a parameter `videoItem` to the callback.

Comment: I see what you mean, but your code still not get the value, thus `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'duration' of undefined`.

Comment: Hey @JianChen Thanks! That helped me! +1.  Any chance you know if there is a cap on how many video ids you can include in one API call? I can't find it in the docs (yet).